# SSHFS permissions not correct when mounted with fstab

Tags: permissions, security, sshfs

If the SSHFS share in question is mounted manually by the user with the mount command, the permissions are correct and the user has the expected access. No problems.

However, the mount needs to be established automatically (either at boot or on-demand) without user intervention. Unfortunately, if the share is mounted with the following fstab line, the user does **not** have access to the mount point (permission denied), but root does have access (unexpected since we did not include the `allow_root` mount option).

```
mari@sshfs:/home/mari/Documents /home/mari/Documents fuse.sshfs noauto,x-systemd.automount,_netdev,defaults,user,identityfile=/home/mari/.ssh/id_rsa 0 0
```

The [Arch Wiki page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SSHFS#On_demand) includes this example:

```
user@host:/remote/folder /mount/point  fuse.sshfs noauto,x-systemd.automount,_netdev,users,idmap=user,IdentityFile=/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa,allow_other,reconnect 0 0
```

It uses the `allow_other` mount option. However, we do not want to use the `allow_other` mount option because of the security bug described here: https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse/issues/15

The `allow_other` mount option really should not be used without the `default_permissions` mount option, if one cares about security.

However, I'm told that the `default_permissions` mount option does not support ACL's, which is a requirement for us.

What is the correct solution to this issue? We want to automatically mount SSHFS shares and have the permissions and ACL's work correctly.

Comment: Did you manage to get this to work? I'm not using ACLs but I also have  problems getting [on-demand to work](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/467081/sshfs-with-on-demand-mounting). If you get a chance, please could you take a look?