# sshfs with on-demand mounting

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, fstab, sftp, sshfs

I followed instructions for [sshfs "on demand" mounting](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SSHFS#On_demand), but it doesn't work.

I added this to `/etc/fstab`:

```
username@hostname:/ /mnt/remotes/hostname fuse.sshfs noauto,x-systemd.automount,_netdev,users,idmap=user,IdentityFile=/home/stanley/.ssh/my_rsa_key,allow_other,reconnect 0 0
```

Then I ran `sudo mount -a` which did nothing. I also tried `systemctl daemon-reload && systemctl restart proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.automount`.

So I followed the [troubleshooting tips](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SSHFS#fstab_mounting_issues), and used this instead:

```
username@hostname:/ /mnt/remotes/hostname fuse.sshfs ssh_command=ssh\040-vv,sshfs_debug,debug,_netdev,users,idmap=user,IdentityFile=/home/stanley/.ssh/my_rsa_key,allow_other,reconnect 0 0
```

And then ran `sudo mount -av`. In a separate terminal I could access that mount point.

So 1) ssh and sftp are working, 2) sshfs is working, 3) permissions are fine.

So only the on-demand part isn't working - what am I doing wrong?

Comment: By the way, I know about `autofs`, but I don't want to use it because it only works for root.

Comment: it is preferred to use the "edit" link underneath the answer to update it, rather than adding separate comments.

Comment: The comment has nothing to do with the question, I'm expecting an answer of the "why don't you rather use tool XYZ", so I tried to avoid it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The instructions say:

> Note: After editing /etc/fstab, (re)start the required service: systemctl daemon-reload && systemctl restart  where `<target>` can be found by running systemctl list-unit-files --type automount

You have a problem :-(.

Mount options which are implemented by systemd, such as `x-systemd.*`, are not implemented by the `mount` command.

But the `mount` command is what you need to use, if you are an unprivileged user (no root/sudo), and you want to mount an fstab entry (which has been marked to allow this using the `user` or `users` mount option).

Comment: I should have mentioned, I did that too - didn't help - `systemctl daemon-reload && systemctl restart proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.automount`

Comment: Okay the order I issued the commands in was wrong (the instructions are confusing) and so I used the wrong unit file. I added a step by step answer to help anyone else. But you led me the right direction so thank you.

Comment: One more thing: to unmount, is it correct to use `unmount mountpoint` or to use `sudo systemctl stop mnt-remotes-hostname.automount`? You mentioned systemd doesn't work with `mount`, so do I assume the same for `umount`? (both ways work, so I'm unsure which is safer/correct)

Comment: I think `systemctl stop whatever.mount` will undo the sshfs mount.  Then `systemctl stop whatever.automount` will remove the automount so the mount cannot be automatically triggered again. I think `umount whatever` will undo the sshfs mount if it is mounted.  In that sense, I think it may be easier to use systemctl correctly, especially if you have an idle timeout.  I'm not certain what happens if you run `umount` on the bare automount :-).

Comment: But I'm a bit worried about `systemctl stop whatever.automount` if you haven't already stopped the mount unit, after reading https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/6754

Comment: Ok so I'll always do `systemctl stop whatever.mount && systemctl stop whatever.automount` to be on the safe side, and never use `umount`. Thanks for the warning.

Answer (score 5):

The instructions are confusing, especially for someone who doesn't understand systemd.

The correct procedure:

1. add to `/etc/fstab`: `username@hostname:/ /mnt/remotes/hostname fuse.sshfs noauto,x-systemd.automount,_netdev,users,idmap=user,IdentityFile=/home/stanley/.ssh/my_rsa_key,allow_other,reconnect 0 0`
2. run `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`. This creates a systemd "unit file".
3. find out which unit file by running `systemctl list-unit-files --type automount`. For me it was `mnt-remotes-hostname.automount`.
4. enable it: `sudo systemctl restart mnt-remotes-hostname.automount`.
5. `cd /mnt/remotes/hostname` or `ls /mnt/remotes/hostname` and it will automatically create the sftp connection!

That works, but I'm not yet sure about:

- some say `allow_other` is a security risk, I'll need to look into that
- I don't know how to specify when the mount should be automatically unmounted (how many seconds of idle time, etc.)

If anyone can shed light on that, please do.

---

**UPDATE**
As per @sourcejedis's answer, stopping the mount must be done in this order: `systemctl stop whatever.mount && systemctl stop whatever.automount` and one should NOT use `umount mounpoint`!

Comment: `allow_other` should not allow privilege escalation, only denial of service (cause process to hang, it can be killed though). I wouldn't enable it if you don't want the feature it provides, but if you do then I would just do it :-).

Comment: `x-systemd.idle-timeout=` as per `man systemd.mount`

Comment: @sourcejedi Thanks for those missing pieces of the puzzle!

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a really old post, but I just set up an sshfs and ran into a similar issue. For me the solution was to generate a rsa key with no password, because when automounting with systemd automount, you can't be prompted for your identity file password.

Comment: Similarly, you may have to manually ssh (or mount /mnt/remotes/hostname) **as root** first. Otherwise root won't have the server in its .ssh/known_hosts file and may get a confirmation prompt. This prevents the automatic process from authenticating, without printing anything very useful in the logs at either end.